# Sorting Lat and Long Array By Distance in mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting, coordinates, mysql-workbench

I have an array of Lats and Longs that i would like to sort by their distance between each other. I dont have a start or an end lat and long, i just want to sort the array by ascending distance.

What i have doesnt work because i dont have the $lat and $long.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dist.lat,
                dist.lon,
                ( 111.045 * Degrees(Acos(Cos(Radians($lat)) * Cos(
                                         Radians(dist.lat)) * Cos(
                                         Radians(dist.lon) -
                                         Radians($lon)) +
                                         Sin(Radians($lat)) * Sin(
                                         Radians(dist.lat)))) )AS
                distance_in_km
FROM   dist
ORDER  BY distance_in_km ASC;
```

What I have:

```
[[23.454445,-12.33342],[34.45665,-34.555566],[21.222233,-43.444453],
[23.444555,-44.556666],[32.445554,-33.44555788],[23.445598,-67.88909],[54.556677,-66.776655]]
```

I want to sort this array by proximity.

P.S. These coordinates are not real ones.

Comment: Afaik, MySQL does not have arrays. How does your sample table data looks like ? Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I have a table of distance in my sql that have lat, lon and distance columns. What i want to sort is the columns of lat and lon in my table by distance between them.

Comment: Please add the sample tabular data in formatted table to the question, and add corresponding expected output in tabular format as well. Refer the link I shared please